# Dynamically Load Content and Set Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dynamic-content

I have a wizard control that will generate additional wizard pages based on devices selected from one of the screen. Once additional devices are set, the wizard will add create new wizard pages for those devices.

I have a user control 'SDContentTemplate' that is instantiated and the content of a content control is set by an object passed into the constructor. That object is XAML that is loaded from an XML datasource (CDATA).

```
<Section Order="1" RepeatPerDevice="true" Title="Report Data">
  <![CDATA[<DockPanel xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' xmlns:tk="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit">
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Margin="0 0 0 16" TextAlignment="Center">Device X of Y</TextBlock>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock MinWidth="80" Padding="4 2">Manufacturer:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock MinWidth="80" Padding="4 2" Text="{Binding Path=SDDevice.Manufacturer}"></TextBlock>
            </WrapPanel>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock MinWidth="80" Padding="4 2 4 6">Serial Number:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock MinWidth="80" Padding="4 2 4 6" Text="{Binding Path=SerialNumber}"></TextBlock>
            </WrapPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DockPanel>]]>
</Section>
```

The SDContentTemplate control has a public object Device that is set by the code creating this new user control, and I am setting that object when it is instantiated.

The content xaml is all loaded, and everything shows up correctly except the data binding is not working. No data is being displayed within the textblocks. I have tried setting the data context of the 'ContentControl' as well as setting the data context of the 'SDContentTemplate' but I have not been able to figure out how to get the datacontext correctly set so that the textblocks are populated with the data values.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? Am I mistaken and this is not possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I would try setting the ItemsSource property but that is just a reach.  And you can attach a pass through converter so you can see if it gets that far and if it is throwing any errors.

Comment: I was basically setting the data context incorrectly. After I changed the data context of the contenttemplate, I was able to get it working. 

I am thinking I had a slight order of operations issue. 

Thanks for the Snoop suggestion, I definitely like the tool. I marked that as the answer since it helped me find figure out the solution right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest downloading something like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to see what the actual `DataContext` is at runtime

Comment: I have downloaded it and inspected the DataContext which helped me figure out that it was empty when the control was actually being displayed. Thanks for the great advice!